# The reflected impedance from secondary muti-windings

Tags: transformer

If a transformer with only one secondary winding, the reflected impedance from the secondary winding is

$$
Z_{p,eff}=(\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}})^{2} \times Z_{s}
$$

This is a well known equation. But what if there are two secondary windings with turns \$N_{s1}\$ and \$N_{s2}\$ each? The simplified circuit is as below (Note: I put 4 meters in the circuit, and denote the readings beside them):

[image]

What's the reflected impedance to the primary?

Comment: Calculate each secondary independently, then connect them in parallel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Can you give some clues about how to prove it, or some links are ok.

Answer (score 1):

Two "perfect" identical secondaries produce identical voltages and are exactly equivalent to one secondary winding that has the same number of turns as either of the original windings. This means that the loads can be directly paralleled and reflected back to the primary as you would a single load on a single secondary.

Another way to look at is to consider the power in and power out of a perfect transformer with two secondaries. With only one secondary connected to a load dissipating 10 watts, the power into the transformer (ignoring losses because it's perfect) is 10 watts. If you connected up a 2nd identical load to the other secondary, the power into the transformer would be 20 watts.

This would also be the same should the two loads be connected in parallel to just one secondary winding or both windings (respecting phase directions) were wired in parallel and connected to the two loads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about two secondary windings with diffrent turns?

Comment: How about two transformers with parallel primaries and different secondaries with different loads. Do you know how to calculate the impedance seen at the primary side? Hint it's exactly the same as your supplemental question. Let me know if you can't work this out.

Comment: Yes, I can do this work. I just want to get some "confirmation". Because all equations I saw are target on the transformers with only one secondary and one primary.

Comment: Well it's exactly the same method. Just think about it or simulate it and you'll get there.